# Need help for retrofit login example?

Tags: android, retrofit

http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/

in this username and password is part of it i need to post the user entered username and password from edittext and getting json response like this

```
{"Result":"1","UserID":"0"}
```

how to get that json using retrofit . I have successfully made this with asynctask .  But feeling quite difficult to implement through retrofit.
my question is

- Which is the base url?
- in interface which should be exposed in post method.
- How can i get the json response from rest service through json .

Below is my main activity:

```
 package com.example.first.servicefirst;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import retrofit.Callback;
 import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
 import retrofit.Response;
 import retrofit.Retrofit;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText password,userName;
Button login,resister;
ProgressBar progressbar;
TextView tv;

 String url="http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeCode);

    login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
    userName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorfoucs);


    //progess_msz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
      showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"No Network","Please Check Your Network Connectivity",true);
    }

    final   ConnectionDetector    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


          login();

        }
    });


}

public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting alert dialog icon


    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
public void login(){
Retrofit retro = new   
Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://172.16.7.203").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
RetrofitRest retrofitRest = retro.create(RetrofitRest.class);
String s1 = userName.getText().toString();
String s2 = password.getText().toString();
if (s1.equals("")) {
    userName.setError("Enter User Name");
}
if (s2.equals("")) {
    password.setError("Enter Password");
}

retrofitRest.login(s1,s2, new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
});
 }
 }
```

Below is my interface:

```
 public interface RetrofitRest {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/")
Callback<ModelLogin> login(@Query("empcode") String employeecode, @Query("password") String password,       
Callback<ModelLogin> callback);
 }
```

My pojo:

```
 package com.example.first.servicefirst;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ModelLogin {

private String empcode;
private ModelLogin(){}
@SerializedName("Result")
private String result;
public String getResult(){
    return result;
}
private String password;
public String getEmpcode() {
    return empcode;
}


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setEmpcode(String empcode) {
    this.empcode = empcode;
}



public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your request parameters are path parameters you do not need a DTO for your request. Just create a DTO for your response like this.

```
public class LoginResponseDto {
    @SerializedName("Result")
    private String result;
    @SerializedName("UserID")
    private String userId;

    // Getters & Setters etc.
}
```

And lets parse your URL and create your service interface. I think your base url will be "http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/" and other are for service identification. It highly depends on other services you may want to use. If you are just using login service you can even make your base url like this "http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc" but these decisions change your service annotations.

```
public interface LoginService{
    @POST("/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/{employeeCode}/{password}") // Assume your base url is http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/
    public void login(@Path("employeeCode") String employeeCode, @Path("password") String password, Callback<LoginResponseDto> callback);
}
```

And at last your retrofit instance. You should not create your `Retrofit` instance over and over again. Instead create it in your application or use a singleton pattern and get `LoginService` when you need it.

### Update

Since you are using Retrofit 2 you should use a service like this.

```
public interface LoginService{
    @POST("/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/{employeeCode}/{password}") // Assume your base url is http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/
    public Call<LoginResponseDto> login(@Path("employeeCode") String employeeCode, @Path("password") String password);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response bhdrkn my post url  will be like Service at :http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/{EMPLOYEECODE}/{PASSWORD}

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran What do you mean by get url? In your question there is no information about HTTP GET request. You can post user information in employeeCode. I though you are getting employeeCode from your edit text (userName). Are you sure that your url is this "172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login{EMPLOYEECODE}/{P‌​ASSWORD}" than this means your username and passwords are path parameters. Have you tried to get login with other client like Curl? If you post your curl I can help better.

Comment: i tried but getting error like unable to create call adapter for retrofit callback<Modellogin> for method retrofit rest login

Comment: get url in the sense getting response from server as json

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran what is package of your `Callack` class? It should be `retrofit`, (full class name `retrofit.Callback`).

Comment: everything under same package

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran I am not asking your class packages. I am asking which package you import. Do you import retrofit.Callback? Also which retrofit version you are using?

Comment: retrofit.callback am using retrofit 2.0 beta 2

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran Retrofit async service handling is change in 2.0 versions. I updated my answer to cover both versions.

Comment: can i call login method inside onclick event in mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in your Activity

```
private void callLoginApi()
{

    ApiListeners apiListener;

    Retrofit retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/").build();

    apiListener = retrofit.create(ApiListeners.class);

    apiListener.loginUser("test@test.com", "123456",new Callback<String>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void success(String response, retrofit.client.Response arg1) 
            {
                CommonUtills.dismissProgressDialog();
                if(response != null && !response.isEmpty())
                {
                    // Do what you want after getting success
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) 
            {
                // Do what you want after getting failure
            }
        });
}
```

Callback you can change this according to your need

You need to create one interface in which you need to create login API call method

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
public void loginUser(@Field("email") String email,@Field("password") String password,retrofit.Callback<String> response);
```

Comment: getting error like unable to create call adapter for retrofit callback