# Login using retrofit in android having json data at server gives error "Except Begin_object but found string in line 1 column 1"

Tags: android, retrofit

I am having an API in which the params are email and password. The password should be encrypted. As I am using retrofit for the first time.By passing my json online i have generated the model class now.But still facing an error "Except Begin_object but found string in line 1 column 1".I have already spent many hours on this Please help me.

My json is:

```
{
  "result": {
    "userId": 2,
    "userName": "Ram",
    "emailId": "Ram@gmail.com",
    "phoneNumber": "1234567890",
    "eula": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "role": 1,
    "password": "4ba007ae1e4045c3c784fdgefg",
    "creationDate": {
      "date": "2016-12-21 05:45:17.000000",
      "timezone_type": 3,
      "timezone": "India"
    },
    "apiKey": "dsadaskjfhckjhdsfhlksdfsdf4542",
    "lastModified": {
      "date": "2017-02-2 03:25:04.000000",
      "timezone_type": 3,
      "timezone": "India"
    },
    "language": "English",
    "familyId": "",
    "productId": "",
    "partId": "",
    "company": "ABC",
    "address": "xyz",
    "groupIds": "6",
    "notes": null,
    "logo": null,
    "createdBy": 1056,
    "passwordHint": "v$",
    "isArchived": 0,
    "UnSuccessLoginCount": 0,
    "isLocked": 0,
    "lockedTime": {
      "date": "2012:09:02 00:00:00.000000",
      "timezone_type": 3,
      "timezone": "India"
    },
    "lockable": 0
  },
  "message": true
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                String email_enter = email.getText().toString();
                String pass_enter = password.getText().toString();
                String md5pass = md5(pass_enter);
                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
                loginRequest.setEmail(email_enter);
                loginRequest.setPassword(md5pass);
                singinRequest(loginRequest);

            }
        });
 private void singinRequest(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        ApiInterface apiService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<LoginResponse.result> call = apiService.getLogin(loginRequest);
        // Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.loginWithCredentials(new LoginRequest(email_enter, md5pass));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse.result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse.result> call, Response<LoginResponse.result> response) {
                Log.i("REGISTRATION --->", "Registered" + response.body());
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse.result> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("REGISTRATION --->", "Throwable" + t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

LoginResponse.java

```
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private Result result;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private Boolean message;

public Result getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Result result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public Boolean getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(Boolean message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

ApiInterface.java

```
 @POST("/rest/DoLogin")
    Call<LoginResponse.result> getLogin(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
```

Comment: Which is the error? Can you post the Log?

Comment: This error "Service methods cannot return void." occur if i use public void in ApiInterface.java and "no annotation found" error, if i am using the above code

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703737/simple-login-form-with-retrofit), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514454/need-help-for-retrofit-login-example) and [here](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-user-login-and-registration-with-retrofit-php-mysql-and-slim-framework/) as well, skipping the server part

Comment: I have tried,error not coming now.But code is also not working.See my changes  Call<LoginRequest> call = apiService.loginWithCredentials(new LoginRequest(email_enter, md5pass));
                call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginRequest>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LoginRequest> call, Response<LoginRequest> response) {
                       }

Comment: Of course it's not working, `onResponse` is empty.

Comment: But my api,is having data.When i debug the code,it debugs till here "call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginRequest>()". Do u know why?.And i have passed intent in onResponse.

Comment: Your api is having data? That's ok! Put a `Log.d("REGISTRATION --->", "Registered" + response.toString());` inside the `onResponse` method, put a debug breakpoint there, and try again, you'll see a Log with your response

Comment: No response.Actually i have told u that its not moving in function onResponse() after enqueue it stops.

Comment: Does it reaches the `onFailure` method?

Comment: Yes,i have passed the another intent there.Can u tell me,why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoginResponse {

    boolean message;
    result result;

    public LoginResponse(boolean message, LoginResponse.result result) {
        this.message = message;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public boolean isMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public LoginResponse.result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public class result {


        int userId;
        String userName;
        String emailId;
        String phoneNumber;
        int eula;
        int status;
        int role;
        String password;
        String language;
        String familyId;
        String productId;
        String partId;
        String company;
        String address;
        String groupIds;
        String notes;
        String logo;
        String createdBy;
        String passwordHint;
        int isArchived;
        int UnSuccessLoginCount;
        int isLocked;
        String lockedTime;
        int lockable;

        public result(int userId, String userName, String emailId, String phoneNumber, int eula, int status, int role, String password, String language, String familyId, String productId, String partId, String company, String address, String groupIds, String notes, String logo, String createdBy, String passwordHint, int isArchived, int unSuccessLoginCount, int isLocked, String lockedTime, int lockable) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.emailId = emailId;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.eula = eula;
            this.status = status;
            this.role = role;
            this.password = password;
            this.language = language;
            this.familyId = familyId;
            this.productId = productId;
            this.partId = partId;
            this.company = company;
            this.address = address;
            this.groupIds = groupIds;
            this.notes = notes;
            this.logo = logo;
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
            this.passwordHint = passwordHint;
            this.isArchived = isArchived;
            UnSuccessLoginCount = unSuccessLoginCount;
            this.isLocked = isLocked;
            this.lockedTime = lockedTime;
            this.lockable = lockable;
        }

        public int getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public String getEmailId() {
            return emailId;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public int getEula() {
            return eula;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public int getRole() {
            return role;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        public String getFamilyId() {
            return familyId;
        }

        public String getProductId() {
            return productId;
        }

        public String getPartId() {
            return partId;
        }

        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public String getGroupIds() {
            return groupIds;
        }

        public String getNotes() {
            return notes;
        }

        public String getLogo() {
            return logo;
        }

        public String getCreatedBy() {
            return createdBy;
        }

        public String getPasswordHint() {
            return passwordHint;
        }

        public int getIsArchived() {
            return isArchived;
        }

        public int getUnSuccessLoginCount() {
            return UnSuccessLoginCount;
        }

        public int getIsLocked() {
            return isLocked;
        }

        public String getLockedTime() {
            return lockedTime;
        }

        public int getLockable() {
            return lockable;
        }

        public class creationDate {

        String date;
        int timezone_type;
        String timezone;

            public creationDate(String date, int timezone_type, String timezone) {
                this.date = date;
                this.timezone_type = timezone_type;
                this.timezone = timezone;
            }

            public String getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public int getTimezone_type() {
                return timezone_type;
            }

            public String getTimezone() {
                return timezone;
            }
        }

        public class lastModified{
            String date, timezone_type, timezone;

            public lastModified(String date, String timezone_type, String timezone) {
                this.date = date;
                this.timezone_type = timezone_type;
                this.timezone = timezone;
            }

            public String getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public String getTimezone_type() {
                return timezone_type;
            }

            public String getTimezone() {
                return timezone;
            }
        }

        public class lockedTime{
            String date, timezone_type, timezone;

            public lockedTime(String date, String timezone_type, String timezone) {
                this.date = date;
                this.timezone_type = timezone_type;
                this.timezone = timezone;
            }

            public String getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public String getTimezone_type() {
                return timezone_type;
            }

            public String getTimezone() {
                return timezone;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No,it is again throwing same exception

Comment: I will respond you in a while

Comment: Ok,Hey Good morning.Did u find any solution?

Comment: Please refer in the answer below!! This is properly tested!!

Comment: But it is not working for me.I am still getting the exception.

Comment: Yes,In fact i have just do copy and paste in my LoginResponse

Answer (score 0):

Try this out this will work out for sure

```
public class LoginResponse {

    boolean message;
    result result;

    public LoginResponse(boolean message, LoginResponse.result result) {
        this.message = message;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public boolean isMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public LoginResponse.result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public class result {


        int userId;
        String userName;
        String emailId;
        String phoneNumber;
        int eula;
        int status;
        int role;
        String password;
        String language;
        String familyId;
        String productId;
        String partId;
        String company;
        String address;
        String groupIds;
        String notes;
        String logo;
        String createdBy;
        String passwordHint;
        int isArchived;
        int UnSuccessLoginCount;
        int isLocked;
        int lockable;
        creationDate creationDate;
        lockedTime lockedTime;
        lastModified lastModified;

        public result(int userId, String userName, String emailId, String phoneNumber, int eula, int status, int role, String password, String language, String familyId, String productId, String partId, String company, String address, String groupIds, String notes, String logo, String createdBy, String passwordHint, int isArchived, int unSuccessLoginCount, int isLocked, int lockable, LoginResponse.result.creationDate creationDate, LoginResponse.result.lockedTime lockedTime, LoginResponse.result.lastModified lastModified) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.emailId = emailId;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.eula = eula;
            this.status = status;
            this.role = role;
            this.password = password;
            this.language = language;
            this.familyId = familyId;
            this.productId = productId;
            this.partId = partId;
            this.company = company;
            this.address = address;
            this.groupIds = groupIds;
            this.notes = notes;
            this.logo = logo;
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
            this.passwordHint = passwordHint;
            this.isArchived = isArchived;
            UnSuccessLoginCount = unSuccessLoginCount;
            this.isLocked = isLocked;
            this.lockable = lockable;
            this.creationDate = creationDate;
            this.lockedTime = lockedTime;
            this.lastModified = lastModified;
        }

        public LoginResponse.result.creationDate getCreationDate() {
            return creationDate;
        }

        public LoginResponse.result.lastModified getLastModified() {
            return lastModified;
        }

        public int getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public String getEmailId() {
            return emailId;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public int getEula() {
            return eula;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public int getRole() {
            return role;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        public String getFamilyId() {
            return familyId;
        }

        public String getProductId() {
            return productId;
        }

        public String getPartId() {
            return partId;
        }

        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public String getGroupIds() {
            return groupIds;
        }

        public String getNotes() {
            return notes;
        }

        public String getLogo() {
            return logo;
        }

        public String getCreatedBy() {
            return createdBy;
        }

        public String getPasswordHint() {
            return passwordHint;
        }

        public int getIsArchived() {
            return isArchived;
        }

        public int getUnSuccessLoginCount() {
            return UnSuccessLoginCount;
        }

        public int getIsLocked() {
            return isLocked;
        }

        public LoginResponse.result.lockedTime getLockedTime() {
            return lockedTime;
        }

        public int getLockable() {
            return lockable;
        }

        public class creationDate {

            String date;
            int timezone_type;
            String timezone;

            public creationDate(String date, int timezone_type, String timezone) {
                this.date = date;
                this.timezone_type = timezone_type;
                this.timezone = timezone;
            }

            public String getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public int getTimezone_type() {
                return timezone_type;
            }

            public String getTimezone() {
                return timezone;
            }
        }

        public class lastModified {
            String date, timezone_type, timezone;

            public lastModified(String date, String timezone_type, String timezone) {
                this.date = date;
                this.timezone_type = timezone_type;
                this.timezone = timezone;
            }

            public String getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public String getTimezone_type() {
                return timezone_type;
            }

            public String getTimezone() {
                return timezone;
            }
        }

        public class lockedTime {
            String date, timezone_type, timezone;

            public lockedTime(String date, String timezone_type, String timezone) {
                this.date = date;
                this.timezone_type = timezone_type;
                this.timezone = timezone;
            }

            public String getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public String getTimezone_type() {
                return timezone_type;
            }

            public String getTimezone() {
                return timezone;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your `response` request correctly .

```
if(response.issucess()){
 LoginResponse result = response.body();
 if(result.yourMethodToGetData() != null){
   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
   i.putExtra(KEY_BOOK_ID,book.getApiKey());
   startActivity(i);
 }else{
  Loge.e("Error","Error"); 
 }
 else{
  Log.e("Error", "Api result");
 }
}
```

I assume you have an login button.

Now, inside button click listener:

```
if (!userEmail.getText().toString().matches("") && !userPassword.getText().toString().matches("")) {
.......
  LoginRequest loginData = new LoginRequest();
  loginData.setEmail(userEmail.getText().toString());
  loginData.setPassword(your_encrypted_password...userPassword.getText().toString());
  signInRequest(loginData);
.......
}
```

Now, now in `signInRequest()` method:

```
private void signInRequest(final LoginRequest userInfo) {
     ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
     Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.loginWithCredentials(userInfo);
        call.enqueue.....
...............
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply!!! But my debug is not reaching in onResponse it jumps to onFailure and throwing an exception "expected begin_object but was string at line 1 column 1 "

Comment: Where is your LoginRequest classs ?

Comment: Here:-public class LoginRequest {

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @SerializedName("password")
    String password;
    @SerializedName("email")
    String email;
}

Comment: You have an login button or not .

Comment: Yes i have login button.You can see my code contains MainActivity.java all this code is under login button click listener

Answer (score 0):

In Your MainActivity.class
Manage this Line: LoginResponse book = response.body();

```
String email_enter = email.getText().toString();
        String pass_enter = password.getText().toString();
        String md5pass = md5(pass_enter);
        ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.loginWithCredentials(new LoginRequest(email_enter, md5pass));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                Log.i("REGISTRATION --->", "Registered" + response);
                LoginResponse book = response.body();
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra(KEY_BOOK_ID,book.getApiKey());
                        startActivity(i);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("REGISTRATION --->", "Throwable" + t.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);                    }
        });
```

Comment: It is not here,by mistake it was written.I have remove this already

Comment: I think team viewer will be good in ur case..provide me with your team viewer id and pass

Comment: I didn't use team viewer.

Comment: I have already updated my code.I don't know,why the error is coming.